# what is the method for solving Cauchy problem for first order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example:
$$
u_t -uu_x=0,\quad x \in \mathbb{R},\quad t>0.
$$
and $u(x,0)=x$.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) leads to the conclusion that $u(t,x)$ is constant on the lines $x + u t = constant$.  Taking $t=0$ gives you $x + ut = u$.  Thus $u(t,x) = x/(1-t)$.
Note that this hits a singularity at $t=1$.